# Stacking two images from different satellite providers

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to stack two images from different satellite providers in one GeoTIFF file.
Basically, what I have is a shapefile of South East Asia which I use to clip the two images. I have tried to download them separately and combine them in one single raster file using `R` but with no success since the files are too big.

Now I am trying to do the whole process on GEE but I am getting the an error related with incompatibility between the bands

```
var MyFolder='forestLoop' /// The folder is created automatically
var desc1 = 'forestStack'; /// what I am downloading= name of the file

             
var globcover = ee.Image("COPERNICUS/Landcover/100m/Proba-V-C3/Global/2019")
.select('tree-coverfraction');

// Extract the landcover band
var landcover = globcover.select('tree-coverfraction');
    
// Clip the image to the polygon geometry
var landcover_roi = landcover.clip(table.geometry());
    
// Add a map layer of the landcover clipped to the polygon.
Map.addLayer(landcover_roi);
    


var elevation = ee.Image('CGIAR/SRTM90_V4').
select('elevation');
    
// Clip the image to the polygon geometry
var elevation_roi = elevation.clip(table.geometry());
    
// Add a map layer of the landcover clipped to the polygon.
Map.addLayer(elevation_roi);
    

var combinedImg= ee.ImageCollection([elevation_roi,landcover_roi]).mosaic()


    Export.image.toDrive({
      image: combinedImg,
      description: desc1, 
      folder:MyFolder,
      scale: 100,
      region: table,
      fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
      maxPixels: 2467695321,
      formatOptions: {
        cloudOptimized: true
      }
    });
```

And the error is as follow:

`Error: Expected a homogeneous image collection, but an image with incompatible bands was encountered: First image type: 1 bands ([elevation]). Current image type: 1 bands ([tree-coverfraction]). Image ID: 1 Some bands might require explicit casts. (Error code: 3)`

Here is the link for the code and assets I am using.
https://code.earthengine.google.com/d92b4cbf2a360bc79e531623985370e8

Answer (score 0):

To combine bands from one image with bands from another image, use the [`ee.Image.addBands`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-addbands) method. Your code could look something like this:

```js
var MyFolder = 'forestLoop'; // The folder is created automatically
var desc1 = 'forestStack'; // what I am downloading = name of the file

var treeCover = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/Landcover/100m/Proba-V-C3/Global/2019')
    .select('tree-coverfraction');

var elevation = ee.Image('CGIAR/SRTM90_V4')
    .select('elevation');

var combo = treeCover.addBands(elevation);

var comboClip = combo.clip(table.geometry());

Map.addLayer(comboClip);

Export.image.toDrive({
    image: comboClip,
    description: desc1, 
    folder: MyFolder,
    scale: 100,
    region: table.geometry(),
    fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
    maxPixels: 2467695321,
    formatOptions: {
        cloudOptimized: true
    }
});
```

The [`ee.ImageCollection.mosaic`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-imagecollection-mosaic) function that you're using reduces the intersection of potentially multiple image pixels to a single value per band. The corresponding bands in each image should have the same data type and name. In your example, the land cover image band in position 0 is named `'tree-coverfraction'` and is `uint8` and the elevation image has a band named `'elevation'` as `int16`; the difference is why the error is thrown.